# Issues with Exec.StdIn.Write

Tags: vbscript, cmd, exec, stdin, winscp

I'm trying to use Exec.StdIn.Write in VBScript to call multiple commands in cmd in the same instance of cmd. But it doesn't seem to be working right. I'm not sure if it's just some sort of timing issue, or what. Here's my code (or at least the relevant part that I am currently testing):

```
 Set objWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 strIP = "192.168.1.185"

 strFilePath = "C:\Users\adam\Documents\SQLite3\" & strIP & ".db"

 Set objWinSCP = objWSH.Exec("cmd.exe cd C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP") 
 objWinSCP.StdIn.Write("winscp.exe /console /script=" & strIP & ".txt")
 Do Until boolExist = True
  boolExist = objFSO.FileExists(strFilePath)
 Loop
```

The WinSCP script simply has WinSCP pull a file from my Nexus 7. I've tested that manually in cmd, and it works fine. But when I run the full VBScript the file is never pulled. When Exec is called, and in turn StdIn.Write is used, StdIn.Write does wait for execution of the previous Exec statement, correct? If it doesn't, then I guess this is probably just a timing issue. I honestly am having trouble finding much of anything on the details of StdIn.Write. I've even seen people suggest using StdIn.Writeline instead. Though I'm not sure what the difference is there. I've only ever actually used the Exec method once or twice before, to be honest. And that was just for one command call in cmd. So I'm kind of lost here.

I have also tried using only one Exec call to get this done. But that doesn't work either. And I need to get it all working, anyway, since there is another part of my script which would require multiple commands in a cmd instance.

I have also checked to make sure that I have a recent enough version of Windows Script Host for Exec to be included. And I have Ver. 5.8, which is the latest version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you not just make one liner with `.Exec`? `"cmd.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe /console /script=" & strIP & ".txt"`. I would put in some quotes around the file path.

Comment: I could. That's true. I mainly just wanted to split it up. But I also need to get StdIn.Write working either way. Since I need to use it for another part of my script. I just posted this part of it because the other part is like 6 times as long. I suppose I should have mentioned that beforehand. But using only one line for this reveals that the issue seems to lie in the Exec call to begin with. Just one Exec call isn't working, either. But I'll edit my original post to explain all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
' VB Script Document issues-with-exec-stdin-write_done
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sResult: sResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim objWSH, oExec, cmdLine

Set objWSH = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell")

cmdLine = "cmd.exe /K CD ""C:\Program Files\""&dir A*&pause"
' minimum: 
' cmdLine = "cmd.exe /K"
'
Set oExec = objWSH.Exec( cmdLine)
' follows in next line: wait for StdOut stream (MyStd_IO function)
sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & MyStd_IO( "", "vesy...", 30)

cmdLine = "CD %userprofile%&dir a*&pause" & VbCrLf
' CD %userprofile% : a cmd command to run (an example)  
' &                : ampersand indicates multiple commands line 
' dir a*           : other, next cmd command to run (an example)
' &                : 
' pause            : force (unique) determined string in StdOut stream
'                  : 
' VbCrLf           : tell "our command line ends" to command processor
'
' follows in next line: run some commands, collect StdOut stream 
sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & MyStd_IO( cmdLine, "vesy...", 30)
' cmdLine    : our (multiple commands) command line
' "vesy..."  : PAUSE command standard output (ending in my language)
' 30         : time limit (in seconds) to wait for std. output

sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & MyStd_IO( "exit", "", 1)

Set oExec = Nothing
Wscript.Echo sResult
Wscript.Quit

Function MyStd_IO( byval strCmd, byval strTxt, byval secsLimit)
' Provides access to the StdIn and StdOut (not StdErr) streams
'   of a WshScriptExec Object (within a script run with Exec Method) 
' Returns StdOut output stream of the oExec object
' Input parameters:
' strCmd    : text to write to StdIn input stream of the oExec object
'           : (no StdIn.Write if empty string)
' strTxt    : text stating end of StdOut output stream of the oExec object
'           : (no StdOut.Read if empty string). Language dependent,
'           : defaults to English output of PAUSE command
'           : "any key to continue..."
' secsLimit : time limit (in seconds) to wait for StdOut output stream
'           : (waits infinite if zero)
'
  MyStd_IO = "***" & vbTab & strCmd & vbNewLine 
  Dim ii : ii = 0 '' loop pass counter
  If oExec.Status = 0 Then 
    Dim timeStart :  timeStart = Now
    MyStd_IO = MyStd_IO & vbNewLine
    If strCmd = "" Then
    Else
      oExec.StdIn.Write( strCmd)
    End If
    If strTxt = "" Then
      ' no 
    Else
      Do While True
        ii = ii + 1
        If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
            MyStd_IO = MyStd_IO & oExec.StdOut.Read(1)
            If InStr( MyStd_IO, strTxt) <> 0 _
              Or InStr( MyStd_IO, "any key to continue...") <> 0 _
                Then Exit Do
        End If
        WScript.Sleep 1
        If secsLimit = 0 Or DateDiff( "s", timeStart, Now) < secsLimit Then
        Else
          MyStd_IO = MyStd_IO & vbNewLine & "!!! MyStd_IO" & "!!! time limit !!!"
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop
      If oExec.Status = 0 Then oExec.StdIn.Write( VbTab) 'any key to continue
    End If
  Else
    MyStd_IO = MyStd_IO & " WshScriptExec object status: WshFinished"
  End If
  MyStd_IO = vbNewLine & ii & "× " & MyStd_IO 'add  
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I tried that out, and it still isn't working. It just hangs indefinitely. I even tried limiting the wait time to 40 seconds. Still nothing. So I'm thinking it might be an issue with Exec. I'll go ahead and try testing Exec with as simple a command as possible and see what happens. If it doesn't execute properly, then I'll know that it's an issue with Exec. I'll append the results to my original post once I get a chance to test.